# where is field defined in ng-model="field"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a beginner in Angularjs and I want to know where the field is defined in the following Angular 1.3.0 code. I am using a dependency ngMessages from where I have taken this code for a form on my page. But I am unable to understand what field is referring to here. I mean, I can figure out what it is pointing to(the div right below it) but where exactly have we made the relation? All I could get from the  Angular-messages.js was

" we have a text input named `myField` which is bound to the scope variable field using the `{@link ngModel ngModel}` directive."

So I also logged the $scope and found nothing related to field. Please, Someone explain me how it is related to the div below.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
      Enter text:
      <input type="email" ng-model="field" name="myField" required maxlength="15" />
  </label>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">Please enter a value for this field.</div>
      <div ng-message="email">This field must be a valid email address.</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength">This field can be at most 15 characters long.</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Here is my entire code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRj1rJRGclwcOscKq6xO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-model binds html text field with angularjs controller,so here

ng-model bind the value of email text field with $scope.field in your controller,here is the sample code:

html code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <div data-ng-controller="your-controller">
 <form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter text:
   <input type="email" ng-model="field" name="myField" required        maxlength="15" />
  </label>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter a value for this field.</div>
    <div ng-message="email">This field must be a valid email address.</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">This field can be at most 15 characters long.</div>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</html>
```

controller code:

`var myApp=angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('your-controller',function($scope){ 
    console.log($scope.field); 
});`

Comment: As `$scope.field` is not setted in the input when the controller is created, your `console.log()` will prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you define any `ngModel` in form(HTML) without initiliazing it in the controller,

that `ngModel` become part of `$scope` associated with the `controller` of your template.

In your case its look like your `ngModel` `field` is not initialised in the controller.

But its part of `$scope` of the mapped controller.

```
<input type="email" ng-model="field" name="myField" required maxlength="15" />
```

Here `name` and `ngModel` are the same.

In the angular form,your `input control` is accessible using form name.

```
myForm.myField //your_form_name.form_field_name
```

If you want to check `$scope` contents then you should print it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`ngModel` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

> The `ngModel` directive binds an `input`, `select`, `textarea` (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using `NgModelController`, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.

---

When you write `<input ng-model="field"/>`, `fields` is binded to the **scope** of your controller (`$scope.fields`).

If you didn't initialize it in your controller, `fields` is probably `undefined`.

Comment: I just added a link to my code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRj1rJRGclwcOscKq6xO?p=preview). You can see there its clearly working and I have initialized my controller yet the value is undefined. That's what my question is, why is that value undefined when the docs clearly say it is binded to the scope of my controller.